# LLDB Python API how do I know a thread is exited?

Tags: macos, lldb, arm64

How do I know if an `SBThread` has exited or finished running the code ?

I wrote an LLDB script to track all the fn calls made by a program since its start. The loop is supposed to end after the last `exit` call, but in reality, it never does and the thread continuously executes with an invalid Program counter. This is my script :

```
import lldb

def run_program(debugger, command, result, internal_dict):
    target = debugger.GetSelectedTarget()
    print("target is %s"%(target,))
    debugger.SetAsync(False)
    l = lldb.SBLaunchInfo(argv=[])
    error = lldb.SBError()
    l.SetLaunchFlags(lldb.eLaunchFlagStopAtEntry)
    process = target.Launch(l, error)
    thread = process.GetThreadAtIndex(0)
    start_fp = None
    while not thread.is_stopped:
        thread.StepOver()
        frame = thread.get_thread_frames()[-1]
        if not start_fp or start_fp != frame:
            print("%s::"%(frame,))
            start_fp = frame
    return


def __lldb_init_module (debugger, dict):
    #adds a command `rp` (type rp in the lldb prompt)
    #this will execute a python function that keeps stepping until the frame is switched and then print info about the frame
    debugger.HandleCommand('command script add -f %s.run_program rp' % __name__)
```

```
lldb --file vector
(lldb) target create "vector"
Current executable set to '/Users/draklor40/gowind-whisper/vector' (arm64).
(lldb) command script import run_program.py
(lldb)
```

After the `exit()` my loop keeps running :

```
frame #0: 0x00000001006990f0 vector`main(c_argc=0, c_argv=0x0000000000000000, c_envp=0x0000000000000000) at start.zig:501::
frame #1: 0x000000018c51be50 dyld`start + 2544::
{ 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 79 }
1
frame #0: 0x000000018c56a058 dyld`dyld3::MachOFile::isSimulatorPlatform(dyld3::Platform, dyld3::Platform*)::
frame #0: 0x000000018c51be64 dyld`start + 2564::
frame #0: 0x000000018c85df68 libdyld.dylib`dyld4::LibSystemHelpers::exit(int) const::
frame #1: 0x000000018c51be9c dyld`start + 2620::
::
::
::
::
::
::
::
::
```

From the [documentation](https://opensource.apple.com/source/lldb/lldb-310.2.36/www/python_reference/lldb.SBThread-class.html), it says, `is_stopped` is True ONLY if thread is stopped but not exited. How do I know if a thread is exited ?

Answer (score 0):

When a thread has exited, the lldb SBThread object representing it is no longer valid, and can't answer questions.  So the first check - before your "is_stopped" check, should be `thread.IsValid()`.  If that returns `False` then that thread has exited.

The "SBThread.IsValid()" check is also wired up to the "bool" function in Python, so:

```
if my_thread.IsValid():
```

and

```
if my_thread:
```

are equivalent.

lldb doesn't currently track thread exit events, however, so there's no way to get lldb to inform you proactively when a thread exits.  You have to check it before you use it.